# Display Oracle query result from a servlet to jsp

Tags: database, jsp, servlets

what i like to do is to have a jsp page. 
This page has a menu bar.

When the user clicks on an item in the menu bar, a piece of java code should be called in a servlet. 
This java code should query the db.

The result from this query should be added to request.setattribute()

So it can be displayed in the jsp page.

Someone who can set me up with this?

Comment: What in particular do you need help with?

Comment: in particular with how to call the java code to execute the query and how to do the servlet mapping in web.xml

Comment: There are any number of tutorials that discuss servlet mapping and JDBC, I'd recommend starting with one of those.

Comment: This isn't freelancer!

Answer (score 0):

Just link to the servlet with the data in the query string.

```
<a href="/path/to/servlet?dataKey=dataValue"> Link text </a>
```